# select value from table that exist on another table condition by id value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two table tablea and tableb

tablea(id PK)

```
id  value              
__________
1     a
2     b
3     c
4     d
5     e
6     f
7     g
8     h
9     i
10    j
```

tableb(id PK)

```
id  value
__________
1     a
2     d
3     c
4     h
5     e
6     f
7     j
8     d
9     d
10    j
```

I want to compare these tables by id 
i.e {1,3,4,5,6}
if id  of tablea and tableb values are Same then i want Number of rows in return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT tablea.id
     , tablea.value AS valueA
     , tableb.value AS valueB
FROM tablea INNER JOIN tableb
  ON tablea.id = tableb.id
WHERE tablea.value = tableb.value
  AND tablea.id IN(1,3,4,5,6)
```

Then you can count the rows as well :

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS commonRows
FROM tablea INNER JOIN tableb
  ON tablea.id = tableb.id
WHERE tablea.value = tableb.value
  AND tablea.id IN(1,3,4,5,6)
```

Comment: I need for selective 5 id {1,3,4,5,6 } help me.

Comment: Do you mean the result of SELECT should be a string concatenating all ids found ? @user3368534

Comment: SELECT should be these ids only 1,3,4,5,6                                              Select * from tablea where id IN(1,3,4,5,6). like that

Comment: OK, I got it. @user3368534

Answer (score 2):

Count how many rows (joined by id) have the same value as well :

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM tablea as a
  JOIN tableb as b ON a.id = b.id
WHERE a.value = b.value
```

Comment: It gives Count for total 10 rows I need selective 5  id {1,3,4,5,6}.

Comment: Add "AND a.id in (1,3,4,5,6)" in the WHERE clause

Comment: @SorinJ you've contributed to the correct anwser. So I want to give you an upvote ^^

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM tablea a
INNER JOIN tableb b ON a.id=b.id AND a.value=b.value;
```

Comment: tablea and tableb values should be the same